# Display a flag link in views based on whether the node has an associated taxonomy term

Tags: flags

All of my nodes of a certain content type are given a category by assigning a taxonomy term. I would only like to add the flag, "My Fruits" if the content has the term "Fruit" assigned to it.

So far I've attempted using a views PHP field to add the flag:

This works to simply print the flag:

```
<?php 
print flag_create_link("basket_01_t01_fruit", $row->nid);
?>
```

But this, I'm not able to get working:

```
<?php 
if ($row->field_item_produce_type == '3') {
print flag_create_link("basket_01_t01_fruit", $row->nid);
}
?>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this easily using views without using views php field. More specifically you can create a view of content with an [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) (entity views attach) field display where you will add the flag link field and attach it to the nodes of that content type. Just make sure to:

1. Add a contextual filter of Content:Nid
2. Add a relationship of "Content:Taxonomy terms on node"
3. Also add a "Flags: Node flag" relationship (uncheck the include flagged content only checkbox)
4. Add a filter "Content type:...your content type which nodes will have the flag link
5. Add a filter "Taxonomy term: Term ID" that will equal to the tid of the "fruit" term.

After that you can easily choose how to display this eva field on your nodes using [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Comment: Thanks, after some effort I was able to accomplish this with your suggestion.

Comment: Cheers. Glad to help.